# Dragging an OFFSET function across a row not producing desired results

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this but I've googled and googled and haven't come across it.

I have 2 excel sheets the first sheet is weekly performance data that takes up 4 columnms  ie sales, prospects, appointments and commissions.  There is one blank column separating each weekly group.

On my second sheet I am trying to summarize the weekly data in column form under week one there is the total sales, total prospects, appointments and commissions.

I am trying to use the OFFSET function =OFFSET(Sheet1!S139,0,5)  where S39 is the first week sales total, the second weeks sales total is 5 columns over and the third is 5 columns after that.

The first instance works great, but when I try and drag the formula across the row it doesn't work.  The next cells formula is =OFFSET(Sheet1!T139,0,5) when it should be =OFFSET(Sheet1!X139,0,5).

What am I doing wrong?

I hope I explained this clear enough.